# return physical port speed of Cisco switch over SNMP

Tags: cisco, snmp

If I set a `bandwidth` parameter to Cisco Catalyst family switch port like this:

```
s1#sh run int Fa0/4 | i band
 bandwidth 15000
s1#
```

..then `ifHighSpeed` no longer returns the physical port speed, but instead the `bandwidth` value:

```
$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c public s1 ifHighSpeed.5
IF-MIB::ifHighSpeed.5 = Gauge32: 15
$
```

Is there a way to return physical port speed over SNMP even if `bandwidth` is specified? I tried with `portAdminSpeed`(`.1.3.6.1.4.1.9.5.1.4.1.1.9`), but SNMP agent in my switch does not know about that.

Comment: What do you mean with physical port speed? I.e. if a port supports 10/100/1000 and the 'auto' settings results in a speed of 100, do you want to get 100 (current speed) or 1000 (max speed) ? If you do a "show interface", where does it show the info you are looking for?

Comment: Also, what model of Catalyst are we talking about and which IOS or IOS-XE version are you running, that may sometimes be relevant.

Comment: @hertitu If a port supports 10/100/1000 and the `auto` settings results in a speed of 100, then I want to get 100 (current speed). Switch model is `WS-C3560X-24` with IOS version `15.0(2)SE8`.

Comment: Time and hardware restrictions don't allow me to test right now, but you may have a look at the RFC2668-MIB, e.g. do a walk of 1.3.6.1.2.1.26.2.1.1.11, but note that the return value is not the speed but a type which you can look up [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/ianamau-mib/ianamau-mib). I guess it's not what you're looking for though as it at first sight this seems to return the port type, not the operational speed.

Comment: @hertitu I tried with `WS-C3560X-24` SW version `15.0(2)SE8` and few other Cisco Catalyst family switches and those did not support `1.3.6.1.2.1.26.2.1.1.11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've just tried this on an older 3750 (`12.2(52)SE`) and here's what I get - given the following configuration:

```
interface FastEthernet1/0/1
 switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 1,5,500
 switchport mode trunk
 bandwidth 5000
 spanning-tree link-type point-to-point
!
```

SNMP gives back the bandwidth value for the `ifSpeed` OID (bps):

```
IF-MIB::ifSpeed.10001 = Gauge32: 5000000
```

and a value of `5` for the `ifHighSpeed` (Mbps):

```
IF-MIB::ifHighSpeed.10001 = Gauge32: 5
```

Now, knowing that the `ifIndex` for `fa1/0/1` is `10001` on this switch, I walked the entire MIB grepping for that index number, and there isn't a single relevant OID that gives a return value of `100000000` or `100`.

So, long story short, it doesn't look like it is possible to return the physical link speed when the `bandwidth` parameter is set.

Comment: Interestingly enough on the Nexus 3048 (NXOS System version: 6.0(2)U6(4)) it is exactly opposite. They only provide the physical speed... Love Cisco very much...

Answer (score 0):

If you need speed information of Interfaces, you can test `ifSpeed`(OID:`.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.5`, **FROM RFC1213-MIB, IF-MIB**). It's worked for me.

Comment: Both `ifHighSpeed` and `ifSpeed` will return bandwidth value.

Comment: typical!  To be honest though, I would expect that to be the behaviour anywhere.  The  bandwidth parameter is only for protocols like OSPF to use in link costs.  The ifMIB is all about physical characteristics

Answer (score 0):

The physical port speed is signified by the interface type name.  In your case, `int Fa0/4` means `interface FastEthernet 0/4`.  Fast Ethernet means 100Mbps. However, a subrate Ethernet port can be achieved with the `speed` command.  The hardware speed (full or subrate) is often called the *port speed*.  The *circuit* speed can be configured with traffic shaping or policing.

So that's 2 distinct keys terms, port speed and circuit speed.

Try [mediaIndependentInputSpeed](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3273.txt) or [CISCO-IF-EXTENSION-MIB](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/v2/CISCO-IF-EXTENSION-MIB.my)